# Bluemix Single Sign On app throws a consent error not related with the SPS

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

I deployed in Bluemix a Single Sign on app using the following tutorial. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/se-bluemix-single-sign-on-app/index.html
When running this app outside the company firewall, it works fine. When inside the firewall, I get the following error below. It took me a while to figure out this was due the firewall. How to workaround this issue? Thanks.

```
An error occurred fulfulling the current request to /mtfim/sps/default/oidc/consent. This is not a problem with the SPS.

Time:2015-05-06T09:55:14Z
Request address:/mtfim/sps/default/oidc/consent
Error details:An error occurred fulfulling the current request to /mtfim/sps/default/oidc/consent. This error was caused by an internal/unexpected error on the invoked protocol module. Please validate configuration of the executing protocol and environment. This is not a problem with the SPS.
```

Comment: I am a little confused...  Are you saying its working inside of Bluemix but its not working inside your corporate firewall?

Comment: I thought he was saying that from inside the corp firewall his SSO login front the browser is failing because of a blocked url or something.

Comment: I'm a little confused as well... if you are following the tutorial as is, you are using Eclipse + IBM Bluemix tools for Eclipse. Where are you getting this error? Eclipse console? if so, please put in here the full stack trace of the deployment. From Bluemix web console? Please also put the stack trace.

Comment: This error is thrown when clicking the signin URL that pops up the SSO login window. In other words when the Redirect URI is called back. I just made some additional testing and I only get this error in Chrome. It works fine in Firefox for some reasons.

Comment: You can try the SSO in the app available here: http://pocpointdurs.mybluemix.net/. Click on Sign-In with a SIS to reproduce. Again the error only occurs in Chrome on my side.

Comment: I've tried in both web browsers and I'm successful in both. Which SIS are you testing?

Comment: Hi Lionel. Another person is also having this problem. Not sure why the callback is throwing this problem on Chrome only :(

Comment: Same experience here. It fails with Chrome but it works with Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

I just got exact same error you did in Chrome, but this only happened after reloading my app's login URL that redirects to the SSO service, immediately after I had changed some settings on the Single Sign on Service. I then tried Firefox and it worked fine.

So I then killed my Chrome session and restarted Chrome, and it now works it works fine in Chrome too.

So I think it will work for you if you just start a new session in Chrome.